# Why is my logo not showing up on my navbar, but other logo yes?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to create a navbar, but when I load my website in localhost, I can't seem to see my logo on the navbar. So I went searching on the web to get an example to see if my logo was the problem. In this first example ( took from the web I can see their logo loading)

```css
    *{transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;}
    
    .container{
      clear:both;
      overflow:auto;
    }
    
    nav{float:right;}
    
    .logo img{float:left;}
    
    ul li{
      display: inline-block; padding:10px;
      font-size:20px; font-family:raleway;
    }
    
    ul li:hover{
      color:orange;
      
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Intel-logo.svg/2000px-Intel-logo.svg.png" alt="" width="130"/>
      </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Services</li>
      <li>Products</li>
      <li>Clients</li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <hr />
```

Then all I did is put the direct link of my imgur image to replace their logo by mine and when I load it, it doesn't show up. How come?

```css
    *{transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;}
    
    .container{
      clear:both;
      overflow:auto;
    }
    
    nav{float:right;}
    
    .logo img{float:left;}
    
    ul li{
      display: inline-block; padding:10px;
      font-size:20px; font-family:raleway;
    }
    
    ul li:hover{
      color:orange;
      
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jSo9sj9.png" alt="logo" width="130"/>
      </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Services</li>
      <li>Products</li>
      <li>Clients</li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <hr />
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It works for me in chrome exactly how you have it.

Comment: Try clearing your cache and hard-reload

Comment: Ok so the problem is on my end ? Kinda weird how their logos show up and not mine for me.

Comment: Runs fine for me and runs fine in the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I put it in the body element and got rid of the `</hr>` and it’s working for me. [image][image]

It also works on jsfiddle.net.
   [image]

Comment: The problem is definitely on my end then, because i tried with your code and i still don't see it :/

Comment: i tried with pycharm and brackets, same result for both.

Comment: My only guess is maybe imgur is blocked by a anti-virus filter?